# PHP: Show directory NAME and not a period (".")

Tags: php, directory

How do I get PHP to return the NAME of the current directory that the php file is in, and not "."?

What we're doing is having one master index file copied to each folder and presenting the images it finds in each folder necessarily.  Now we need to remind the user what folder they're currently in!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `basename(realpath('.'))`, See:

- [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)
- [basename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Answer (score 4):

use `__DIR__` or, before PHP 5.3, `dirname(__FILE__)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`realpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function for that.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [getcwd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

```
<?php

// current directory
echo getcwd();
```

Or [realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) as mentioned below. `realpath` is generally more useful as you are not restricted to the current working directory.